# MPI & OpenMP: omp_get_max_threads returns half of the true thread capacity

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, openmp

For an unknown reason, when I compile with MPI `omp_get_max_threads()`, the number of threads returned (12) is half of the capacity my computer has (24 threads, 12 cores). This strange behaviour appeared without reason for two days now, while everything was working well before. I have installed MPI from [source](https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v4.1/openmpi-4.1.1.tar.gz). I tried to install it again in the same way but still faced the same problem.

I have read several posts, and seen the `oversubscribe` or the `omp_set_dynamic()` solutions, but I am not satisfied with neither of these, because I am running a cluster with different type of machines, and I really want to determine the maximum number of threads dynamically.

How can I find the variables driving the default result of `omp_get_max_threads()` ?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  int provided;
  MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_SINGLE, &provided);

  //int num_cpu = omp_get_max_threads();
  //omp_set_dynamic(0); 
  //omp_set_num_threads(4); 
  std::cout << omp_get_max_threads()<< std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

Compiling it with `mpicxx not_fun.cpp -fopenmp -o not_fun`. If I execute it with `./not_fun` result is 24, which is correct. If I execute it with `mpiexec -np 4 ./not_fun` result is 12, not correct.

### Additional information

I am not sure if this is related.

I ultimately had a problem with my RAM, and one stick is not working properly so I removed it. It could perhaps be related, but I don't think so. I installed again MPI with the new RAM configuration, and still got the same problem.

Comment: You're supposed to use `MPI_Init_thread` if you use multi-threading.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my code and tried your solution, but still get the same problem. It doesn't seem to affect the maximum number of threads

Comment: Keep in mind MPI might pin tasks on a subset of cores (Open MPI pins tasks on sockets by default - or cores if 2 MPI tasks). You also do **not** want your OpenMP threads to end up time sharing.

Comment: In your case, I guess MPI tasks are pinned to sockets, and hence 12 cores per task. But you are running 4*12=48 OpenMP threads on a 24 cores node (time sharing => suboptimal performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what a thread is. A thread is a software construct, having nothing to do with hardware. Try writing a program that prints out the number of threads, and do `OMP_NUM_THREADS=321 ./yourprogram` It will report both the max and actual number of threads to be 321. If you want something relating to the number of cores, use `omp_get_num_procs`. (And just to be clear: the number of threads comes from the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable, or any explicit override in your source.)

If you write an MPI program, and you do the same thing, you'll find that (probably) each MPI process gets an equal number of "procs" and multiplying MPI procs (on one node) and OMP procs will be less equal than the core count. But that may depend on your implementation.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this explanation. It makes some things clear. I wasn't aware about this 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' override when running. It does make the trick.

Comment: That's an environment variable. In my explanation I set it for just one command, but you can set it more permanently with `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=17; ./yourprogram`.